# AsyncPlayerChatEvent setCancelled doesn't work

Tags: java, bukkit

```
      @EventHandler
      public void onPlayerChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent event){
          String msg = event.getMessage();
          List<String> words = Main.plugin.getConfig().getStringList("swear-words");
          for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++){
              if(msg.contains(words.get(i))){
                  event.setCancelled(true);
                  event.getPlayer().sendMessage("You are not allowed to swear!");
              }
          }
      }
```

he does give the message "You are not allowed to swear!" but he does not delete the chat message

Comment: Use event priority, `@EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.LOWEST)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the error comes from an already cancelled event, so I'd do another thing next to rgnt's comment, I'd also ignore all the cancelled events:

Add `@EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.LOWEST, ignoreCancelled = true)`